# Finding a small, low-actuation pushbutton

Tags: components, button, actuator

I'm looking for a small kind of pushbutton that I'm not even sure exists.

I want it to have these properties:

```
Width: 7mm (Will compromise for 5mm-10mm)
Travel distance of 2mm (Will compromise for 0.5mm-2.5mm)
Actuation force: 40g (Will compromise for 40g-45g)
```

I've emailed a bunch of suppliers but none of them have a button like that.

Is anyone aware of a button like that?

Is there anywhere where I could post a cash bounty for someone to find a button like that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take any button and add an appropriate spring assembly and build something that suites your needs.

An excellent selection of buttons are here: http://mouser.com

A primer on selecting springs can be found here: http://www.centuryspring.com/pdfs/12-228compression.pdf

Comment: I should mention that you need to factor in the push force required for the button as it will be added to the force of the spring.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the Panasonic catalog; I found EVQ-PH recently, something similar would suit you: http://www.panasonic.com/industrial/components/pdf/linecard_switch.pdf

Comment: Actuation is way too high.

Answer (score 0):

I sell [these](http://www.voti.nl/shop/p/SW-20.html) small (box is 5 x 4 x 8 mm) switches:

[image]

But these are surplus (not recommended for production). I got them from electronic goldmine, but they are out of stock there. No clue how they would be called.

Comment: Since (a) I have no idea what their actuation force is and (b) I can't use them in production, I think I'll pass. Thanks!

Comment: a) neither have I, but it is very low compared to all other buttons I have. b) indeed, but the picture might give you a hint what to look for (alas, there is no code or manufacturer mark on the black box).